# How to output variable contents to "LogCat" window in Android-ndk

Tags: printing, android-ndk

I am using Android-sdk-ndk in an Eclipse+ADT environment. In Android-sdk Java development, I could use "Log.i", "Log.w", ... statements to output messages and variable contents to the "LogCat" window. However, in Android-ndk C/C++ development, is there any similar C/C++ "print-like" statement that outputs messages / variable contents from a JNI C/C++ module to the "LogCat" window so that I could have some debug informations for my program.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Lawrence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this guide: http://www.srombauts.fr/2011/03/06/standalone-toolchain/

You can #define the logging methods like this:

```
#define LOGI(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "hello-ndk", __VA_ARGS__))
```

And you need to make sure you're linking to liblog by compiling similar to this (just add `-l log`):

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc  hello-ndk.c -l log -o hello-ndk
```

Comment: In Android Studio 1.0+, the way to add -l log, is to add a line `ldLibs 'log'` to the ndk block in app/build.gradle - see http://sdgsystems.com/blog/using-android-ndk-android-studio/