# How to use adb socket to get the result from the phone?

Tags: android, adb

I have written an executable file, and push it into /system/bin.

After run the file, it will give a result in float.

Now on PC side, I want to get this result.

At first I write this float number into a file and use 'adb pull' to pull this file, then read file.
Because I need to do this operation frequently, may 2 times per sec. This cause bad performance of the phone.

Wheather it will be little influence when I use adb socket?
Where my executable file should output?
How adb socket get the result?

Thanks.
James.

Answer (score 1):

If you're leaving the phone connected, you could probably just do

```
adb shell /system/bin/myexecutable
```

and just have your binary print its output to stdout.  As long as your program runs quickly, twice per second shouldn't be too fast.  Otherwise, you could do

```
adb shell cat /somewhere/myoutfile
```

to see what's in a file currently.

Comment: I want to use the result, and adb shell command cause the phone bad performance when I use it frequently.

Comment: That surprises me that you get bad performance.  Could you quantify that?  If you want to use the result you can do that easily though -- just pipe the output of either command wherever you want to.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean of "just pipe the output of either command wherever you want to." PC's op system is win7. In my application, there is a timer(1 sec), if it periodically call adb shell command, it may cause application not response.

Comment: ah, my bad.  I was assuming a linux system where piping makes sense.  On my system running adb shell once per second isn't a problem... sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially use `logcat` as a medium for getting data from your Android app to your desktop machine provided there is an ADB connection available.

My thinking is that there are two pieces:

1. Log your app output with logcat to a unique TAG on the Android side.  For example,

   ```
   Log.d("MyAppOutput", "This is the output I am looking for");
   ```
2. On the desktop side, you could run a command line that looks specifically for that TAG, something like:

   ```
   adb logcat -s MyAppOutput
   ```

I believe this would allow you to read the results from the Android app in near realtime.  If you need to know the timestamp of the log message, you could add the `-v time` parameter to prefix each message with a timestamp.

Comment: I don't have an Android app, the executable file just get the CPU usage, now I am trying to write a server to monitor a port, on PC side, send command to inform the server to send result.

Comment: Since your question states you've written an executable, I assume you have access to the source.  Could you not modify the executable to write its output to logcat instead of a file.  It could run in a loop and write to logcat multiple times a second for your PC app to read.  This would mean you never have to pull any files and just continually tail logcat.

Comment: My executable is writed with C language, how to modify it's output to loacat? And I think the background progress which run a loop in the phone may consume phone's limited CPU and memory.

Comment: I assume you are using NDK.  Check this link (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8814101/591801) to write to logcat.  The bg process shouldn't consume phone's resources if it is simply waking up after 500ms and running a quick scan then sleeping.  Certainly it wouldn't be any more load than the current implementation.

Comment: This idea helped me alot, so i gave it a +1. Though its seems not to answer the question. But I searched for an easy way to check if my app started and runs properly on android. This is a good way for me to check

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question before, you don't need output result to file, just output your result to a socket port, and use adb forward to get the result on your pc by adb socket. this is what you need solution.

adb forward tcp:18000 tcp:19000

this command means，pc's tcp port 18000 bind to device's tcp port 19000, if you send data to 18000 port on pc, you can get data from 19000 on device.vice versa.